# Переход из одной activity в другую

Tags: android

Начал писать приложения для android
При нажати на кнопку должна открываться другая activity, но вместо это приложения на эмуляторе почему то вылетает.

```
    private View.OnClickListener mOEnterClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ProfileClass.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
};
```

В манифесте обе activity прописаны.
В разметки страницы вроде ошибок нет

Выводится вот такая ошибка:

```
2021-02-20 21:11:58.045 15327-15351/com.example.week_3 E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008cdf
2021-02-20 21:11:58.045 15327-15351/com.example.week_3 E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008cdf
2021-02-20 21:11:58.046 15327-15351/com.example.week_3 E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008824
2021-02-20 21:11:58.046 15327-15351/com.example.week_3 E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008824
```

Comment: а с какой ошибкой вылетает?

Comment: @Andrew он просто пишет программа приостановлена попробуйте снова

Comment: @даниласоловьев это на устройстве пишет. А нужно смотреть `Logcat` в студии!

Comment: @AndreyMihalev  отредактировал вопрос и добавил туда ошибку

Comment: [Ответ на английском SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39057187/android-app-error-glutilsparamsize-unknow-param)